# Calculate scrollbar thumb size

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I'm creating a scrollbar for a popup window. The problem I'm having is trying to calulate the height of the thumb size on the scroll bar.

In the below image are 3 parts

1. This is the content height. This can expand infinitly
2. This is the thumb. I want the minimum height to be 1, and the maximum to be the height of the actual scroll bar.
3. This is the scrollbar where the thumb is inside of.

[image: Example]

Having the thumb stay between a certain height is easy:

```
_thumbHeight = MathHelper.Clamp(_thumbHeight, 1, _scrollbarHeight);
```

What I need is to calculate in the `_thumbHeight` using the `_contentHeight`, and `_scrollbarHeight`.. I think!

Comment: Its not clear what you are after.  The thumb scales according to the area to scroll.  If you are inheriting from ScrollBar you'll get that behavior.

Comment: @Plutonix - this entire scrollbar system is created manually by me. The only bit I'm struggling with is the size of the thumb.